# Why is sizeWithFont for whole words different from the sum of sizes of its letters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uifont

Why does `sizeWithFont` for whole words produce a different result from the sum of the sizes of its letters?

Here is an example for text with and without kerning:

```
CGFloat fontSize = 36;
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];

NSArray *wordsToTest = @[@"IIIIIIIII", @"VAVAVAVAV"];

for (NSString *testWord in wordsToTest) {
    CGFloat widthOfTextWithFont = [testWord sizeWithFont:font].width;

    CGFloat widthOfTextUsingIteration = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < [testWord length]; i++) {
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(i, 1);
        NSString *nextLetter = [testWord substringWithRange:range];

        widthOfTextUsingIteration += [nextLetter sizeWithFont:font].width;
    }

    NSDictionary *attributesKerningDisabled = @{NSFontAttributeName : font,
                                                NSKernAttributeName : @0.0F};
    NSAttributedString *attributedStringWithDisabledKerning = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:testWord attributes:attributesKerningDisabled];


    NSDictionary *attributesKerningEnabled = @{NSFontAttributeName : font,
                                               NSKernAttributeName : @1.0F};
    NSAttributedString *attributedStringWithEnabledKerning = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:testWord attributes:attributesKerningEnabled];


    NSLog(@"Test for string: %@", testWord);
    NSLog(@"Length of the whole word: %f", widthOfTextWithFont);
    NSLog(@"Length of word, using iteration: %f", widthOfTextUsingIteration);
    NSLog(@"Length of attributed string with enabled kerning: %f", [attributedStringWithEnabledKerning size].width);
    NSLog(@"Length of attributed string with disabled kerning: %f", [attributedStringWithDisabledKerning size].width);
}
```

And here is the result:

```
Test for string: IIIIIIIII
Length of the whole word: 84.000000
Length of word, using iteration: 90.000000
Length of attributed string with enabled kerning: 93.000000
Length of attributed string with disabled kerning: 84.000000

Test for string: VAVAVAVAV
Length of the whole word: 204.000000
Length of word, using iteration: 206.000000
Length of attributed string with enabled kerning: 200.000000
Length of attributed string with disabled kerning: 204.000000
```

And here is part of Apple documentation:

> NSKernAttributeName
>   The value of this attribute is an NSNumber object containing a floating-point value. This value specifies the number of points by which to adjust kern-pair characters. Kerning prevents unwanted space from occurring between specific characters and depends on the font. The value 0 means kerning is disabled. The default value for this attribute is 0.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably due to kerning. Kerning is the process of changing the spacing between consecutive letters to make the text look and read better.

When you get the size of the full string, kerning will be applied. For individual characters there is nothing to kern so ho spacing considerations can be made.

([Kerning on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning))

---

I do not believe that your use of `NSKernAttributeName` turns off kerning. I think the use of the term 'kern' in this case is inaccurate and it actually refers simply to additional spacing between characters, not the kerning defined for the font.

Comment: I use NSAttributedString and set NSKernAttributeName = 0 (Kerning disabled). The width of attributed text with disabled kerning returns same value as [mainText sizeWithFont:boldFont].

Comment: That setting doesn't turn off kerning I think, it just allows you to add additional spacing...

Comment: I changed my example to show you difference for text with enabled and disabled kerning.

Comment: Additionally, when you are calculating each of the letters length, some approximation or rounding off is happening. This is happening as many times as you have any number in the word. So cumulatively this is giving you a margin of error. As a result, for 9 letter word, you are getting length difference of 2, I bet if you use a 20 letter word, the difference will be even larger.

Comment: Wain you can believe whatever you want but I showed you both cases in my example. Kerning works and it can make text wider or narrower.

Comment: True, it has an effect - what I'm saying is that I don't believe setting the value to zero is disabling font kerning, it's just not adding additional kerning. Test with a fixed width font and see what happens.

Comment: NSKernAttributeName The value of this attribute is an NSNumber object containing a floating-point value. This value specifies the number of points by which to adjust kern-pair characters. Kerning prevents unwanted space from occurring between specific characters and depends on the font. The value 0 means kerning is disabled. The default value for this attribute is 0.

Answer (score 1):

As @AnindyaSengupta note it the round up is different if you round up the sum of all glyphs advances for the whole text or if you round up each glyphs advances.
Two CoreText functions that illustrate the differences  :

```
/* round up the the advances for the whole text */
static double getTextAdvances(NSString *text, CTFontRef font)
{
    unichar *characters = malloc(sizeof(unichar) * text.length);
    CGGlyph *glyphs = malloc(sizeof(CGGlyph) * text.length);
    CGSize *advances = malloc(sizeof(CGSize) * text.length);

    [text getCharacters:characters range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)];
    CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(font, characters, glyphs, text.length);

    CTFontGetAdvancesForGlyphs(font, kCTFontHorizontalOrientation, glyphs, advances, text.length);

    free(characters);
    free(glyphs);

    CGFloat sum = 0.;
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
        sum += advances[i].width;

    free(advances);

    // round up the whole advances
    return ceilf(sum);
}

/* round up each glyphs advances */
static double getCharactersAdvancesSum(NSString *text, CTFontRef font)
{
    unichar *characters = malloc(sizeof(unichar) * text.length);
    CGGlyph *glyphs = malloc(sizeof(CGGlyph) * text.length);
    CGSize *advances = malloc(sizeof(CGSize) * text.length);

    [text getCharacters:characters range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)];
    CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(font, characters, glyphs, text.length);

    CTFontGetAdvancesForGlyphs(font, kCTFontHorizontalOrientation, glyphs, advances, text.length);

    free(characters);
    free(glyphs);

    CGFloat sum = 0.;
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
        // round up advance width
        sum += ceilf(advances[i].width);

    free(advances);

    return sum;
}

    // test method
    CGFloat fontSize = 36;
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];

    NSArray *wordsToTest = @[@"IIIIIIIII", @"VAVAVAVAV"];

    for (NSString *testWord in wordsToTest) {
        // … snip

        NSLog(@"Test for string: %@", testWord);
        NSLog(@"Length of the whole word: %f", widthOfTextWithFont);
        NSLog(@"Length of word, using iteration: %f", widthOfTextUsingIteration);
        // … skip kerning logs
        NSLog(@"Round up whole text advances %f", getTextAdvances(testWord, (CTFontRef)font));
        NSLog(@"Round up per Characters Advances %f", getCharactersAdvancesSum(testWord, (CTFontRef)font));
    }
```

Test results :

```
Test for string: IIIIIIIII
Length of the whole word: 84.000000
Length of word, using iteration: 90.000000

Round up whole text advances 84.000000
Round up per Characters Advances 90.000000

Test for string: VAVAVAVAV
Length of the whole word: 204.000000
Length of word, using iteration: 206.000000

Round up whole text advances 204.000000
Round up per Characters Advances 206.000000
```